# Starting out with PHP

Tags: php

So I have a static website and now I want to add some PHP into it. I made lots of google searches but I don't get how to start it up. I know I need a server and stuff but I think I will stick with some free web hosting for now. Where do I start? What do I need to start out, is there a coding platform I can use with PHP. I am using Brackets.io right now and I really want something like that where I can live preview the PHP.

Comment: https://www.google.ro/search?q=how+to+start+using+php

Comment: For basic PHP code checkout tutorialspoint or w3school websites

Answer (score 0):

you should try [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/). It's free, and you can follow their website design course, which details the implementation of PHP.